# Subsetting data.frame to return first 200 rows for specific condition in r

Tags: r, subset

I have a `data.frame` with 3.3 million rows and 9 columns. Below is an example with the 3 relevant columns.

```
StimulusName Subject Pupil  Means
1            1       101    3.270000
2            1       101    3.145000
3            1       101    3.265000
4            2       101    3.015000
5            2       101    3.100000
6            2       101    3.051250
7            1       102    3.035000
8            1       102    3.075000
9            1       102    3.050000
10           2       102    3.056667
11           2       102    3.059167
12           2       102    3.060000
13           1       103    3.085000
14           1       103    3.125000
15           1       103    3.115000
```

I want to subset data based on stimulus name and subject and then take either the first few or the last few rows for that subset. So, for example returning row 10 and 11 by getting the first 2 rows where `df$StimulusName == 2 & df$Subject == 102`.

The actual data frame contains thousands of observations per Stimulus and Subject. I want to use it to plot the first and last 200 observations of the stimulus separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not tested this out, but should work.

**First 200**

`df_filtered <- subset(df, StimulusName == 2 & Subject == 102)
df_filtered <- df_filtered[1:200,]`

Then plot `df_filtered`.

**Last 200**

`df_filtered <- subset(df, StimulusName == 2 & Subject == 102)
df_filtered <- df_filtered[(nrow(df_filtered)-199):nrow(df_filtered),]`

Then plot `df_filtered`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I was able to solve it in a similar way so this works ya :)

Comment: Great! If so, can you select this as best answer (pressing the check mark button) so your question is marked as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
subCond <- function(x, r, c) {
  m <- x[x[, 1] == r & x[, 2] == c,]
  return(m)
}
```

Yields e.g.:

```
> subCond(df, 1, 102)
  StimulusName Subject PupilMeans
7            1     102      3.035
8            1     102      3.075
9            1     102      3.050
```

or

```
> subCond(df, 2, 101)
  StimulusName Subject PupilMeans
4            2     101    3.01500
5            2     101    3.10000
6            2     101    3.05125
```